# What is Program Id of Metadata Program on Devnet?

Tags: anchor, metaplex

I'm testing a program which integrates TokenMetaData Program by Metaplex. I wanted to check what is the program id of the same on devnet?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can find the address in the code and the docs like https://metaplex-foundation.github.io/metaplex-program-library/docs/token-metadata/index.html#PROGRAM_ADDRESS

It’s the same for devnet and mainnet-Beta:

metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s